# Best practice for [python] CI/CD workflow

Tags: continuous-integration, workflow, github-actions

I am looking for recommendation for CI/CD workflow. My pipeline is using GitHub Actions but that is not that important.
I currently have one single workflow that on each push/PR:

- check out the code
- Build the wheels for three platforms
- Run the tests on all three platforms
- Deploy the artifacts on PyPI
- Generate and deploy the doc on GitHub pages

This is obviously inefficient (generating a release for each push is questionnable :) ).
I wanted to split the workflow in 3 having:

1. for building and testing on a single platform,
2. an other workflow for generating the 3 artefacts called once a release is decided
3. one for the doc that could be triggered once artefacts are generated (not sure how though)

Happy to hear what you think (is|are) the best workflow(s)